# Cordova 3.0 on iOS : Plugin method not being called

Tags: ios, plugins, cordova, native

I am trying to follow the guide located here:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide

and especially this one

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_plugin.md.html#iOS%20Plugins

I followed exactly all the steps, but somehow the plugin is not working. The native echo method is not being executed when I try to call the JavaScript part.

In order to be sure that the plugin is loaded, I've implemented the pluginInitialize Method. It seems that the plugin is loading fine.

The logging output:

```
2013-10-28 13:04:16.824 AirPrototype[2288:18e03] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-10-28 13:04:16.840 AirPrototype[2288:18e03] Echo plugin init.
2013-10-28 13:04:16.841 AirPrototype[2288:18e03] [CDVTimer][echo] 0.748992ms
2013-10-28 13:04:16.841 AirPrototype[2288:18e03] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.354039ms
```

The implementation:

```
#import "Echo.h"
#import "../Cordova/CDV.h"
#import "../Cordova/CDVPlugin.h"

@implementation Echo

- (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    NSString* echo = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if (echo != nil && [echo length] > 0) {
        NSLog(@"echo called with arg %@",echo);
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:echo];
    } else {
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR];
    }

    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

- (void)pluginInitialize
{
    NSLog(@"Echo plugin init.");
}


@end
```

I've registered the plugin with:

```
<feature name="Echo">
    <param name="ios-package" value="Echo" />
    <param name="onload" value="true" />
</feature>
```

Created a javascript function definition:

```
window.echo = function(str, callback) {        
    cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
        callback('Nothing to echo.');
    }, "Echo", "echo", [str]);
};
```

And call the plugin with

```
window.echo('echome', function(echoValue) {
    alert(echoValue == 'echome'); // should alert true.
});
```

But it does not work.

I only noticed that the Safari debugger complains with:

Failed to load resource : The requested URL was not found on this server.

The URL which was not found seems to be file:///!gap_exec?1382961871341

Did anyone have this issue already? Or am I doing something completely wrong? What am I missing here?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Greetings
MP

Comment: Are you waiting for onDeviceReady to be called before calling your plugin?

Comment: Yes. I am listening for the event and it is correctly being fired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research and digging the code it seems to be a Phonegap/Cordova bug.

This problem only occurs if a CDVViewController is added as a subview to a regular UIViewController.

In this case the method viewControllerForRequest of the class CDVURLProtocol fails finding the correct ViewController class. I just did a quick hack hack and return my only CDVViewController in any case.

Maybe I'll fix it and submit a patch later.

Comment: Thanks dude.After digging the code 2 days.Finally I found this thread and instead of add pushed the view and it works.

Comment: Is this still an issue? It looks like I'm running against the same problem. If it look at `viewControllerForRequest` it never returns a valid viewController throughout the apps lifecycle. It also refuses to look for the controller in `gRegisteredControllers`.